# Launching teleop_twist_keyboard from launch file along with other nodes messes up the logs in the terminal

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am launching the teleop_twist_keyboard node along with some other nodes from a launch file. In all nodes, I have set the "output" argument to "log" so that they do not log into the terminal except for one node (not the teleop_twist_keyboard one). However, the logs in the terminal are messed up, namely there are a lot of extra spaces which makes it very difficult to read them. I found out that this issue is caused by the teleop_twist_keyboard node even though I have set the "output" to "log", because when I am not launching it from the launch file but instead I am rosrun-ing it from another terminal, the logs of the launch file are correct.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387546/launching-teleop_twist_keyboard-from-launch-file-along-with-other-nodes-messes-up-the-logs-in-the-terminal/) by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2021-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't necessarily call this an "issue", but more an unfortunate consequence of how `teleop_twist_keyboard` is implemented and how that interacts with the way `roslaunch` coordinates / starts things.

In summary: `teleop_twist_keyboard` uses certain bits of infrastructure to be able to read your keyboard presses from the terminal it was started in. `roslaunch` wraps `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` and then changes the way these interact with the terminal.

To work-around this you could start `teleop_twist_keyboard` in a separate terminal. You can do this with a [launch prefix](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB). Something like `xterm -e` should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on 2021-09-29**:
Ok thank you a lot for your help!!